# Memory optimization of redis-server in an embedded Linux distribution

Tags: memory-usage, redis, virtual-memory, embedded-linux

I'm trying to optimize a **redis-server version 6.0.5** installed in an embedded Linux distribution with 2 GByte of RAM.
At the moment there aren't particular failure of the redis-server.

The output of the `top` command regarding redis-server is showed below:

```
Mem: 1539492K used, 342412K free, 80900K shrd, 21288K buff, 412440K cached
CPU:   9% usr   4% sys   0% nic  85% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 1.24 1.32 1.30 1/132 89546
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ %CPU COMMAND
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  248     1 redis    S    1079m  58%   0% /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I would like to highlight the following values:

- for redis-server the higher value in `top` output is `%VSZ = 58%`.
- used Memory is **1539492 K** (of 2 GB = **2097152 K** that is the total RAM)
- only **342412 K** of memory is free

---

### Without redis-server

Without the process redis-server (I have execute the command `systemctl stop redis`) the output of the command `top` become:

```
Mem: 605764K used, 1276140K free, 81576K shrd, 26832K buff, 417608K cached
CPU:   0% usr   0% sys   0% nic  98% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 0.27 0.15 0.37 2/126 97764
```

In this context the values relative to the memory are:

- used Memory is **605764 K** (of 2 GB = **2097152 K** that is the total RAM)
- now **1276140 K** of memory is free

---

**QUESTION**: When redis-server is running on my system:

1. the `%VSZ` value is a too high value?
2. the memory used is too much?

Comment: Keep in mind that "vsz" column is not the resident or shared size. I'm not too sure what exactly it is.

Comment: @DanielB thanks. I don't know what "vsz" is me too..